# Set color in variable

Tags: php, sql

I want to set the color of the variable to red or green depending on the condition of the variable , it should appear red or green if its more and less than 0 respectively. But , the echo-ing is not allowing me to do so in the sense that the profitandloss echoed each row the has no color set.Because the rest of the row is all retrieved from database .So i would also need to echo it out. I know the method im doing is wrong. The rows are echoed on a row by row basis so the color is dependent on the value. So how do i get the colors to work by a per row basis??

```
    if($profitandloss<$zero){
         "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>";
    }
    elseif ($profitandloss>$zero)
         "<div style=\"color: green;\">$profitandloss</div>";
 // }
    // for profit and loss counting
 //

    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['trade_id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['selection'] . "</td><td>" . $row['date'] ."</td><td>" . $row['type'] ."</td><td>" . $row['size'] ."</td><td>" . $row['bidprice'] ."</td><td>" . $row['offerprice'] ."</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] ."</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] ."</td><td>" . $profitandloss  . "</td><td><a href ='delete.php?id=".$row['trade_id']."'>X</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Clarify your question. I dont know exacly what you're looking for. You need to color rows in your table depending on `$profitandloss < $zero` condition, or just add static value before all rows? Is `$profitandloss` value calculated for each row in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for - inserting simple condition in a row:

```
echo "<tr style=\"color: ".($profitandloss > $zero ? 'green' : 'red')."\"><td>" . $row['trade_id'] . "</td><td>" . (...)
```

or just save your result to variable and use it in the row:

```
if($profitandloss<$zero) {
    $profitText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>";
} elseif ($profitandloss>$zero) {
    $profitText = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$profitandloss</div>";
}
```

in your row place it like that:

```
echo '(...) <td>Profit: '.$profitText.'</td> (...)';
```

Comment: Thanks for the right answer i was looking for , rather than spotting php and html errors.

Comment: @nigel your comment sounds like you're complaining about our spotting of coding errors in your question. Bear in mind that you have to understand what's wrong with your code to be able to learn. Although i mentioned your incorrect usage in your code, I also suggested a correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not echoeing anything there. Your PHP script is full of errors. You can't just mix and match HTML and PHP this way.

When doing IF statements, you need to 'echo' (or store in variables) the HTML parts inside a string, and concatenate the variables to them. This way the page will display only the value of the PHP variables when rendered into HTML

```
if($profitandloss<$zero){
    $red_div =  "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>"; // notice echo here
}
elseif ($profitandloss>$zero) { // you had missed this brace?
    $green_div = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$profitandloss</div>"; 
}
```

then you need to output the two divs in the correct table locations.

Comment: I know im not echoing. thats not the way to do it . i need it inside the table

Comment: If you need to use it later, then save them in variables and put them in the table afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `echo`

```
 if($profitandloss<$zero){
      echo "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>";
  } elseif ($profitandloss>$zero)
      echo "<div style=\"color: green;\">$profitandloss</div>";
  }
```

Comment: i know that but i want it to echo below . base on conditions